# If 0 eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity of one then V = ker T (+) Im T

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can anyone help prove it?
Sounds easier than it really is :(

If 0 eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity of one then
$$
V=\operatorname{Im}(T) \oplus \operatorname{ker}(T)
$$
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghjos.png

Comment: It's better to write out the question in full in the body than to ask people to chase it offsite.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $\ 0\ $ is an eigenvalue of $\ T\ $ of algebraic multiplicity one, then the characteristic polynomial $\ p\ $ of $\ T\ $ must have the form $\ p(x)=x(xq(x)-t)\ $, where $\ t\ne0\ $.  So by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem,
$$
T\big(Tq(T)-tI\big)=0\ .
$$
If $\ v\in V\ $, and $\ v_1=v-t^{-1}Tq(T)v\ $, what is the relation between $\ v_1\ $ and $\ \ker T\ $? If $\ v_2= t^{-1}Tq(T)v\ $, what is the relation between $\ v_2\ $ and $\ \text{Im}\,T\ $?